# How to Integrate an Image into Middle of Text Labels in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm new to SwiftUI, and I want to place an image inside a text, similar to the example image below:

[image: Example image]

While I can add an image at the beginning of the label using

```
Label("You can also edit the text.", systemImage: "pencil.line")
```

I'd like the image to be integrated within the text.

Comment: Thanks Mr. [rob mayoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77567/rob-mayoff), for enhancing the question's presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI, you can effortlessly combine multiple text elements into a single text by [+ operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/+(_:_:)) and incorporate images within that text. Here's how you can place an image inside your text:

```
Text("You can also ")
 + Text(Image(systemName: "pencil.line"))
 + Text(" edit the text")
```

### Applying Modifiers:

You have the flexibility to apply modifiers either individually or collectively to text elements.

**Collective Modifier Application:**

To apply modifiers collectively, enclose all text elements within the first set of parentheses and then apply the modifier as shown below:

```
(Text("You can also ")
 + Text(Image(systemName: "pencil.line"))
 + Text(" edit the text"))
    .font(.title2)
    .fontWeight(.medium)
    .foregroundStyle(.green)
```

**Applying Modifiers Individually:**

You can easily apply modifiers to individual text elements, just as you would with any other view in SwiftUI.

```
Text("You can also ")
    .font(.title2)
    .fontWeight(.medium)
    .foregroundStyle(.green)
+ Text(Image(systemName: "pencil.line"))
    .fontWeight(.bold)
    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
+ Text(" edit the text")
    .italic()
    .fontWeight(.bold)
```

Comment: Many thanks, @Abdullah, for your quick and informative reply.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to know:

- You can combine two `Text`s into one larger `Text` using [the `+` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/+(_:_:)).
- You can turn an `Image` into a `Text` using [a `Text` initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/init(_:)-60ax7).

Thus:

```
(
    Text("You can also ")
    + Text(Image(systemName: "pencil.line"))
    + Text(" edit the text.")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with localization (i.e. the position of the image may change depends on the language), you might want to use `NSMutableAttributedString` with `NSTextAttachment`, you can insert an image by replacing a placeholder substring with the attachment.

You can use `UIViewRepresentable` to fit your `NSAttributedString` into a SwiftUI view.